# Providing configurable default instance

Tags: c++

Is there a canonical pattern / best practice way in c++ to provide a default instance of a class, whose constructor requires parameters? It should e.g. be usable like this:

```
int main() {
    //At startup:
    //Parameterize default instance with some runtime Data
    Foo::initDefault(getConfigFromFile().getDefaultFooVal());

    //1) Use default instance somewhere else in the code:
    Foo::getDefault().doSomething();

    //2) 
    Foo::getDefault().doSomethingElse();

    //3) somewhere else in the code, maybe even before the call to initDefault()
    Foo myFoo(5);
    myFoo.doSomething();
}

void bar(const Foo& foo = Foo::getDefault()) {
    //... do something with foo
}
```

Note that

1. 1) and 2) operate on the same instance
2. As 3) shows,`Foo` is not a singleton
3. I want to avoid providing a default constructor

Comment: Will this instance be shared among the whole program? Is it kind of singletone with extension of giving another instances?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: Pretty much yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to allow a "default" instance, I would use a pointer to indicates the presence of the singleton instance:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int i){...};

    static Foo& initDefault (int i) {
        static Foo foo(i);
        if (pFoo) {
            throw "Foo's instance is already initialized.";
            // or: foo = Foo(i); if you want to allow re-initialization
        }
        else {
            pFoo = &foo;
        }
        return foo;
    }

    static Foo& getDefault() {
         if (!pFoo) {
             throw "Cannot get Foo's instance before initializing it.";
         }
         return *pFoo;
    }  

    void doSomething(){...}

private:
    static Foo *pFoo;
};

Foo* Foo::pFoo{nullptr};
```

With the above, you have a simple way to test if the instance is initialized without having to dynamically allocate your singleton instance.

Answer (score 2):

My usual approach looks like this:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int i){...};

    static Foo& initDefault(int i){
        static Foo foo(i);
        return foo;
    }

    static Foo& getDefault() {
         static Foo& foo = initDefault(-1);
         return foo;
    }  

    void doSomething(){...}
};
```

Comment: If you don't want to allow the creation of `initDefault(-1)` (which is like a default constructor which you do not want apparently), you could have a private static attribute, e.g. `pFoo` initialized to `nullptr` (`static Foo *pFoo = nullptr;`) and then set `pFoo` to `&foo` in `initDefault` so that you can test in `getDefault` if `pFoo` is `nullptr` and throw an exception accordingly.